# Gmaps4Rails link issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I'm using Gmaps4rails and reading some lat, long locations to plot on a map. It works fine, but each icon I click on always goes to the last created location. For example if id 4 was the last created it will always go to 4, even if id's 1,2 or 3 are selected.

Json

```
{"status": "ok", "data": {"latitude": -50.3317, "name": "Station", "longitude": 159.77}}
```

Controller

```
@temperatures = Temperature.all

@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@temperatures) do |data, marker|
 meta = JSON.parse(open(data.location).read)
 marker.lat meta['data']['latitude']
 marker.lng meta['data']['longitude']
 marker.json link: temperature_path(data)
end
```

View

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    points = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
    markers = handler.addMarkers(points);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
        var link = points[i].link;
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i].getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
          window.location.href = link;
        })
      }

      handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
</script>
<div style='width: 100%;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 600px;'></div>
</div>
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    points = [{"lat":-27.7189,"lng":151.416,"link":"/temperatures/1","marker_title":"Soil Station"},{"lat":-30.2275,"lng":149.72,"link":"/temperatures/2","marker_title":"Soil Station"}];
    markers = handler.addMarkers(points);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
        var link = points[i].link;
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i].getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){ window.location = link;})
      }

      handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show the generated html?

Comment: added it above. hope this is what you're after.

Comment: not sure of the closure issue, check the workaround here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6hp5LrqYHa1xc7AYhJh?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closure issue, here is an elegant way to solve it:

```
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    var points = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(points);

    _.each(points, function(point, index){
      google.maps.event.addListener(markers[index].getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
        window.location.href = point.link;
      });
    })

    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks so much apneadiving. Your contribution and quick answering to these issues is outstanding.

Comment: thanks, I try to demonstrate gmaps4rails is just a wrapper and should never ever add constraints